# Kvetch - Meaning

Tags: american-english, word-usage

I was just reading a book (The Help) and came across a usage of "kvetch" that didn't quite fit with how I thought it was used. A publisher is talking about a person's writing style and comments that she likes the author's writing style because, "She likes to kvetch without complaining too much."

Looking up a couple of definitions for kvetch they all seem to run along the lines of "to complain excessively/consistently".

I was wondering whether people use kvetch with some nuance that the dictionary definitions missed  and what that difference is.

Comment: **kvetch** [*- to complain, especially chronically.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kvetch) Origin: 1960–65,  Americanism; < Yiddish kvetshn  literally, to squeeze, pinch; compare Middle High German, German quetschen*. Presumably your author is favourably disposed to Yiddishisms, and (wrongly, imho) assumes that a *kvetching* Jewish momma is an "affectionate" usage along the lines of *"She's always **fussing** about this and that"* (as opposed to *"She's always **bitching**"*, which would be real "complaining" in a negative sense).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the character in the story was being ironic or humorous--perhaps believing she was doing so at the expense of young Skeeter, considering her to be an ingenue.